# Flash AS3 - dispatch event from class

Tags: actionscript-3

I read a lot about dispatching events and still cant get it to work. I have a class and want it events to be visible for other classes which using this one. Main class:

```
import special.proxy.ProxyStream;
public class testproxy extends Sprite
{
    var textspace:TextField=new TextField();
    var proxydata:*;

    public function testproxy()
    {
        textspace.autoSize="left";
        textspace.text="ready";
        addChild(textspace);
        try
        {
        proxydata=new ProxyStream();
        addChild(proxydata);
        proxydata.load(proxyurl_string, fileurl_string);
        proxydata.addEventListener("COMPLETE", complete);
        proxydata.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
        }
        catch(e:*){textspace.text=String(e);}
        setTimeout(checkProgress, 2000);            
    }

    function checkProgress(){textspace.text=proxydata.progressstate;}

    function complete(){textspace.text="loaded";}
}
```

Class which dispatching event for main class:

```
import flash.events.*;
public class ProxyStream extends Sprite {

    public var progressstate:String="0";
    //[Event(name="complete", type="flash.events.Event")]
    [Event(name="complete",  type="flash.events.Event.COMPLETE")] 

    private function complete(e:Event):void {
        progressstate="1";
        dispatchEvent(e);
        dispatchEvent(new Event("COMPLETE", true, true));
        //dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE, true, true));
        //dispatchEvent(new DataEvent("COMPLETE", false, false, e.target.data));
    }
}
```

As we can see, proxy data is added to display list. And yes, function complete firing, because when I check progressstate after 2 seconds, it has value 1. I tried many different ways of dispatching event. I still cant get this class event in my main class. I also want to be able to send data with this event if its possible without making additional own event class. Thanks for any help.

Comment: try adding listeners before loading

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but your complete-handler in the testproxy class does not have the correct parameters set up (it should be `complete(event:Event)`. That should in fact cause compiler errors.). It might also be helpful if you post the rest of the ProxyStream-class.

Comment: try changing the "COMPLETE" in your dispatchEvent to lowercase. flash.events.Event.COMPLETE == "complete" (lower case)

Comment: Full main class code http://pastebin.com/mB6XqvkK and imported one http://pastebin.com/ZZvrrBKF My output results: 0 [object Stage] 1 2 file://localhost/C:/Documents and Settings/speedy/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/testproxy/bin-debug/testproxy.swf 3 4 5 6 8 9 string 10 11

Comment: function complete(){textspace.text="loaded";} must have an input param i.e. function complete( evnt: Event ){textspace.text="loaded";}

Comment: You are right, I forgot about complete(e:Event). Simpler is sometimes harder to find, thank you =)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complete event lister does not have the correct parameters. It should be `complete(event:Event):void`, not `complete()`

Answer (score 0):

In your `ProxyStream`, simply do `dispatchEvent(e)`, which will dispatch the complete event again from your `ProxyStream` object.

In your `testproxy`, do this:

```
addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

And:

```
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    textspace.text = "loaded"
}
```

The main problem here, I think, is that your handler function does not accept any arguments, which is a runtime error. It should accept one argument.

Answer (score -1):

If I were in your place I would start using the mate framework for Flex.

In a nutshell, its a global event bus for your project.

Comment: Maybe it will be usable for someone who want to know how to send data. I used dispatchEvent(new DataEvent(Event.COMPLETE, true, true, e.target.data)); in ProxyStream class and get it in main class with function complete(e:DataEvent){textspace.text=e.data;} thanks =)